# How to filter white pixesl with javascript on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to filter the image that all white parts are removed and keep the same color?

You can clearly see the white pixels on a black background, is there a way to do this in only javscript / canvas without css?

PS: The images are from a external source

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<img  id="imageID"  src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2822/large/huobi-token-logo.png?1547036992">

<canvas  id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background:black">
</canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("imageID");
    //ctx.filter = 'invert(1)';
    //Is there a way to filter the image that all white parts are removed and keep the same color?
    
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can get the image data and set the alpha value to 0 (or close to zero) based on how close a pixel is to white, **but** you can only do that if the image doesn't arrive "tainted" by being sourced from a different domain. You'd probably be better off getting the image, fixing it in Photoshop or something, and then storing it on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

The image's background isn't white, but transparent. Hence what you're seeing is the black background of the canvas, you just have to fill it with something before copying the image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<img  id="imageID"  src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2822/large/huobi-token-logo.png?1547036992">

<canvas  id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background:black">
</canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("imageID");
    //ctx.filter = 'invert(1)';
    //Is there a way to filter the image that all white parts are removed and keep the same color?
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```